# cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a script that allows me to Noclip through things and Visual Studio is giving me an error but are not being clear on how to fix it.  This was the code:

```
((Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale = Vector3.op_Division(((Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale, 10000f);
```

this is giving the error on the "Vector3.op_Division" Visual Studio is saying "cannot explicitly call operator or accessor" This is not clear on how to fix, yet I believe there is no problem with the code.

I could not do anything as the code would break with anything I did.

MAJOR EDIT: I feel as if I should have called the script that was needed to clarify what I was doing, here is the actual code including the bit before.

```
foreach (MeshCollider meshCollider in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<MeshCollider>())
            ((Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale = Vector3.op_Division(((Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale, 10000f);
```

The solutions you gave did not make sense, and gave more errors, it never came to me that I should give the foreach

Comment: _"I believe there is no problem with the code."_ - what makes you believe that an explicit call to `op_Division` is legal, when it actually isn't? (Though I do agree that C# _should_ allow explicit operator invocation without using actual operators, _le sigh_...)

Comment: Are you doing this in Unity? How about `((Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale = (Component)meshCollider).transform.localScale / 10000f;`?

Comment: $5 says the OP used ILSpy or some other disassembler which showed the explicit `op_Division` call as a normal method call instead of using the operator syntax and they copied-and-pasted it into a new C# project .

Comment: @Dai Thank you, I am just now learning c#, and I didn't know the problem, would there be any fix to make it normal?

Comment: @Benlandistan I posted a full answer 2 hours ago - it's right there below...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `Vector3` type is Unity's `Vector3` (as opposed to [any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=net-7.0) [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb324325(v=vs.85))), then the problem is self-explanatory: C# does not allow overridden operators to be invoked via method-call syntax: you *have* to use the actual operator `/`, even though the C# operator invocation will still be compiled to a normal method-call in the output IL (I don't know why C# has this limitation, I feel it's misguided).

Anyway, change your code to use the `/` operator specifically, like so:

(You should also consider using a new local for the `((Component)meshCollider).transform` dereference otherwise you're evaluating the same expression twice (and the runtime type-check due to the `(Component)` cast might also be more expensive than you think).

```cs
var xform     = ((Component)meshCollider).transform;
var origScale = xform.localScale;
var newScale  = origScale / 10000f; // i.e. op_Division
xform.localScale = newScale;
```